# Trouble converting docker-compose containing volume to Kubernetes manifest

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am learning Kubernetes and I am starting to convert an existing `docker-compose.yml` to Kuberbetes manifest one component at a time. Here is the component I am currently trying to convert

```
version: '3'

services:
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    hostname: mongo-db
    image: mongo:latest
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    volumes:
      - c:/MongoDb:c:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

I am able to log into the Mongo instance when the container is running in Docker but I cannot get this working in Kubernetes. Here is the Kubernetes manifests I have tried so far

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mongodb-data
          mountPath: /data/db
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
      volumes:
      - name: mongodb-data
        hostPath:
          path: "C:\\MongoDb"
```

With this manifest I see the error `Error: Error response from daemon: invalid mode: /data/db` when I do a `kubectl describe pods`.

I understand the mapping of volumes from Docker to Kubernetes isn't 1-to-1, so is this reasonable to do in the Kubernetes space?

Thank you and apologies if this feels like a silly question.

Comment: The couple of WIndows-style paths around this look suspicious.  The `hostPath:` volume in the Kubernetes manifest also doesn't look right; that can cause data to be misplaced if your pod is deleted and recreated on a different node.  Do you need this to be a StatefulSet and not a Deployment, and let the cluster create and provision a persistent volume per replica?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thank you for helping me out. This is a Windows Container and my host OS is Windows. I haven't quite looked into StatefulSet yet but that was going to be my next step in research/discovery. All I was hoping to do was point my pod to the MongoDb folder and then when it is running, log into Mongo running the Pod using Robo3T